# esttab after margins?

Tags: stata

I'm trying to output the average partial effects estimated after a regression but am having some difficulty. I realize using the `margeff` command works around this, but I have some interaction terms in my model and I can't get `margeff` to work with these. I know `margins` works, but when I run the code below, the `.tex` file reports the results of the `glm`.

```
eststo clear
eststo: glm y x1 x2 x3 c.x1#c.x2 c.x3#c.x3, link(logit) robust
esttab using 1.tex, label
eststo clear
glm y x1 x2 x3 c.x1#c.x2 c.x3#c.x3, link(logit) robust
margins, dydx(*)
estimates store margins
esttab using 2.tex, label
eststo clear
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
glm .....
margins, dydx(_all) post
esttab using x.tex, label
```

The key point here is the `post` option in `margins`, that tells `margins` to leave the results behind as if it were an estimation command. This helps because `esttab` looks for stuff left behind by estimation commands.

Comment: Is `margins, dydx(_all)` any different from `margins, dydx(*)`?